# Typescript issue: Type '...' is not assignable to type '...'

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm using nestJS,
I have 2 services,
in the `1st service`:

```
async getOrganizations (attributes: (keyof Organization)[]): Promise<Partial<Organization>[]> { 

    const organizations = await this.organizationRepository.find({select: attributes})
    
    return organizations; 
    //returns [{id:1, name: "x"},{id:2, name: "y"},..]

  }
```

in the `2nd service`:

```
async getOrganizations(): Promise<CustomerResponseDto[]> {
        const attributes : (keyof Organization)[] = ['id', 'name'];

        let organizations = await this.1stService.getOrganizations(attributes);

        organizations = organizations.map((organization)=>{
            return {
                ...organization,
                type: 'Organization'
            }
        })
        
        return organizations;
    //returns [{id:1, name: "x", type: 'Organization'},{id:2, name: "y", type: 'Organization'},..]
    }
```

and the `CustomerResponseDto`:

```
export interface CustomerResponseDto {
    readonly id: number;
    readonly name: string;
    readonly type: string;
}
```

now I'm getting the following error:

```
Type 'Partial<Organization>[]' is not assignable to type 'CustomerResponseDto[]'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type 'Partial<Organization>' but required in type 'CustomerResponseDto'.
    22 |         })
    23 |
  > 24 |         return organizations;
       |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    25 |     }
```

please advise

Comment: Why don't you specify the return type of the map callback, so the compiler can check it: `organizations.map((organization): CustomerResponseDto => ...`. And why reuse a variable that's already implicitly typed as `Partial<Organization>[]`?

Comment: (E.g. [Mre]: https://tsplay.dev/NVa3nw)

Comment: thanks a lot, that was helpful, the issue was related to the variable naming
have a nice day

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It works now, the issue was related to variable naming
in `2nd service`
I changed:

```
organizations = organizations.map((organization)=>{
            return {
                ...organization,
                type: 'Organization'
            }
```

to be

```
const organizationsWithType = organizations.map(({ id, name })=>{
            return {
                id,
                name,
                type: 'Organization'
            }
        })
```